# How to display list_filter with count of related objects in django admin?

Tags: django-admin, django-modeladmin

How can I display the count of related objects after each filter in list_filter in django admin?

```
class Application(TimeStampModel):

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='CI Name', max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="Business application")

class Server(TimeStampModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Server Name', unique=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=constants.COMPANIES.items())
    online = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True, verbose_name='OnLine')
    application_members = models.ManyToManyField('Application',through='Rolemembership',
            through_fields = ('server', 'application'),
            )

 
class Rolemembership(TimeStampModel):

    server = models.ForeignKey(Server, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    application = models.ForeignKey(Application, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Server Role', max_length=50, choices=constants.SERVER_ROLE.items())
    roleversion = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Version', blank=True)
```

---

## Admin.py

```
@admin.register(Server)
class ServerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    save_on_top = True
    list_per_page = 30
    list_max_show_all = 500
    inlines = [ServerInLine]

    list_filter = (
        'region',
        'rolemembership__name',
        'online',
        'company',
        'location',
        'updated_on',
    )
```

i.e After each filter in list filter, I want to show the count of related objects.

Now it only shows the list of filter
i.e location filter list

- Toronto
- NY
- Chicago

I want the filter to show the count like below:

- Toronto(5)
- NY(3)
- Chicago(2)

And if the filter has 0 related objects, don't display the filter.

Comment: do you have any code you're working on so far?

Comment: see example above.

Comment: Are the locations objects? Or string input? Or choices?

Comment: Locations are Choices.

Comment: Is that even possible.  Any ideas on how to go about this ?

Comment: This is possible!  The django docs show an example of dynamic lookups method that inspect the queryset to see which values exist in the data; it is possible to get a count there and include it in the verbose value (second element in the lookup tuple).

One issue is that it counts over the whole model data set, ignoring already applied filters.  I’m trying to solve this at the moment.

Comment: Not tried yet: instead of `model_admin.get_queryset()` (returns all data), call `model_admin.get_changelist().get_queryset(request)` (applies filters, can be expensive)

Comment: Anyone found an actual answer to this? i'm interested as well

Comment: Expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible with a custom list filter by combining two ideas.

One: the `lookups` method lets you control the value used in the query string and the text displayed as filter text.

Two: you can inspect the data set when you build the list of filters.  The docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter shows examples for a start decade list filter (always shows «80s» and «90s») and a dynamic filter (shows «80s» if there are matching records, same for «90s»).

> Also as a convenience, the ModelAdmin object is passed to the lookups
>   method, for example if you want to base the lookups on the available
>   data

This is a filter I wrote to filter data by language:

```py
class BaseLanguageFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('language')
    parameter_name = 'lang'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        # Inspect the existing data to return e.g. ('fr', 'français (11)')
        # Note: the values and count are computed from the full data set,
        # ignoring currently applied filters.
        qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
        for lang, name in settings.LANGUAGES:
            count = qs.filter(language=lang).count()
            if count:
                yield (lang, f'{name} ({count})')

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        # Apply the filter selected, if any
        lang = self.value()
        if lang:
            return queryset.filter(language=lang)
```

You can start from that and adapt it for your cities by replacing the part with `settings.LANGUAGES` with a queryset aggregation + values_list that will return the distinct values and counts for cities.

Answer (score 1):

Éric's code got me 80% of what I needed. To address the comment he left in his code (about ignoring currently applied filters), I ended up using the following for my use case:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class CountAnnotatedFeedFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'feed'
    parameter_name = 'feed'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request).filter(**request.GET.dict())
        for pk, name, count in qs.values_list('feed__feed_id', 'feed__feed_name').annotate(total=Count('feed')).order_by('-total'):
            if count:
                yield pk, f'{name} ({count})'

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        feed_id = self.value()
        if feed_id:
            return queryset.filter(feed_id=feed_id)
```

And then, in the admin model:

```
class FeedEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (CountAnnotatedFeedFilter,)
```

Note: As Éric also mentioned, this can impact the speed of the admin panel quite heavily, as it may have to perform expensive queries.